How to return a character from a string that contains letters and numbers
I want to split a string using Java, but I can't work out the correct regex syntax.
In this example, I want to split “K89” to return “K”.
My code:
String str = "K89";
String[] part = str.split("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d");
System.out.println(part[0]);


what about splitting "K89LM" ? As described you can just use "\\d+" ('into "K"' is not really the result of split. more like a replace or find)

My inputs are just one Letter followed by a number

then "K89".substring(0,1) (or for a char, "K89".charAt(0), assuming single-char letter)

Why do you need to split then? Why not just do str.substring(0, 1)?

How to use charAt? I don’t understand

i try in DSL, this is why I asked for Java they have similar syntax, I receive error both on substring and charAt as the path expression cannot be used on type String

You don't need a split,  you need a replaceAll

DSL? like Domain Specific Language? "have similar syntax" is not enough....

To split between digits and non-digits, you can do this.
String s = "ab828kskf555ksksk";
String[] arr = s.split("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));

prints
[ab, 828, kskf, 555, ksksk]

To remove all digits, you can do this.
String s = "K98";
String removeDigits = s.replaceAll("\\d+","");
System.out.println(removeDigits);

prints
K



This splits on a sequence of digits:
"K89".split("\\d+")


@xtay2 re-read the original post. This is exactly what the OP wants.
